# Planner features compared to SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-planner, planner

We want to have a project management tool inside our Office 365. And we are not sure if we should use Planner or SharePoint lists. now I have more than 10 years of experience in SharePoint, but never used Planner before. so are those features available in Planner: -

1. Can we customize the planner task statuses options, beyond the built-in options?
2. Can we add more columns inside the Planner tasks?
3. When creating a planner task can we define custom permissions? For example, can we define that only the Assigned To user can view the task or can edit it? and after submitting it, only the user manager can approve or reject it?
4. In SharePoint lists doing the permissions and approvals (as mentioned in point 3) is available, but SharePoint lists can only have up to 50,000 items with unique permissions, so in planner do we have the same limitation of the number of tasks that can have unique permissions?
5. Can we customize the planner interface using Power Apps?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions have their benefits, it really depends on what you're looking for:

**Benefits of using Microsoft Planner**

- Ready to use Out-of-the-box.
- Integration with To-Do Lists.
- A number of built-in views are available to help you organize and group tasks.
- Easily integrates with Outlook so you can get notifications on upcoming tasks.
  One downside of using Planner is that it is not possible to add custom metadata fields. Also, there is no such thing as granular security (everyone has the same access to a plan).

**Benefits of using Microsoft Lists**

- Microsoft Lists can serve as a central repository for all your team’s tasks. You can assign tasks to your team, update the status of those tasks, and even have threaded conversations.
- Because of the close integration with Microsoft Teams, you can meet and collaborate on lists at any time.
- You can make as many lists as you want and access them all from a single view. You can also see the tasks that other users have been assigned to.
- View and manage your lists from any location using a web browser, Microsoft Teams, or the mobile version.
- Advanced automation workflows, meaning that you can set rules when certain events occur within a list. For example, when an item is added to a list, an email notification is sent.
- Use built-in templates to quickly create lists such as issue trackers, new hire checklists, and more.
- If you have a large-scale project with many moving parts and people involved, Microsoft Lists is an excellent tool for keeping track of every detail.

[Planner vs. Lists: Which Tool to Use?](https://nbold.co/planner-vs-lists-which-tool-to-use/)

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. when you say Microsoft Lists does this also apply to SharePoint list?

Comment: or you are initially referring to Microsoft Lists and not sharepoint lists?

Comment: Microsoft Lists are powered by SharePoint lists, it's just a different UI for accessing the same thing.